# VScode keyboard short cut react

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsx

I was wondering if there was a shortcut from VS code that would enable me to transform

```
from <component></component> to <component/>.
```

This is using the framework react.js, Thank you!!!

Comment: There are extensions in the marketplace that can do this autoformatting for you. Prettier is a common, opinionated code formatter. There may even just be some local settings to collapse empty tags like this without the need for 3rd-party extensions.

Answer (score 1):

No! There is no inbuilt keyboard shortcut to do this in VS Code as far as I know.

I haven't fully understood your use case. If there are children for this component, you need to apply your own custom logic to handle it once the component tag becomes an inline closing tag.

Nevertheless the most simplest way to achieve what you have asked for is to cut `</component>` closing tag and replace `<component>` opening tag with it.